# How do a Fisher–Yates Shuffle with values in a MongoDB document?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, shuffle

I have a collection that has a bunch of songs each with a value of "index" to state which song is to be played next. How do I preform a [Fisher–Yates Shuffle](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) with all document's "index" values?

Example:

```
[{index:1},{index:2}{index:3}]
```

to

```
[{index:2},{index:3}{index:1}]
```

So far, I have it just grab all of the documents put it in an array do the shuffle and update all values again. But with over 1000 documents i am afraid this is awfully inefficient.

Another idea is to remove index all together and just rely on the collection to keep it organized. This seems the most probable as I can just use $sample to get a random song. But if there is a way to do a proper shuffle with the index values that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is not a question regarding a way to get a random document from a collection but, a way to shuffle the values within the documents. I am wondering if this is possible to do without the needs of sample or loading the entire database.

Comment: Nope. And actually the most efficient thing I can think of you doing here is to basically let `$sample` do the work and then use a `$match` and `$in` on subsequent queries to **exclude** the "played" unique ids in the current cycle, in order to ensure the same thing does not randomly select again. Asking to write to a database in "random order" is not really an efficient thing to ask for. `$sample` has been chosen with the most efficient algorithm as you are going to get. So don't try and re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Just to clear that up. `$sample: { "size": 1 }` on each iteration as opposed to keeping an open cursor using `$sample` over the expected number of results.

Comment: Well, I guess there is nothing better than just using $sample. Thanks :D